# How to apply the rotate effect both closing and opening this select input?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have this down arrow image, which rotates to an up arrow when the boolean "open" function switches, with a transition effect.

```
<img src="./downArrow.png" className={`${(open) && "rotate-180 transition-all"}`} />
```

But when I try to close the container, the arrow goes back to its original state without the transition effect. I tried already a few different ways to apply this effect to (!open) as well but none worked.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the `transition-all` class also gets removed when `open` is false.

To avoid this, move `transition-all` out of the condition:

```
<img src="./downArrow.png" className={`${open && "rotate-180"} transition-all`} />
```

This way, `transition-all` is always present in the class string even when `open` is false.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two problems in your code.
1-The image was not imported properly.
2-There is no transition from 180-0.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from 'react';

function MyButton(){
  const [open ,setOpen]= useState(false);
  return <button onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>Buuton<img src={require("./downArrow.png")}
         className={`${open ? 'rotate-180 transition-all' : ' transition-all'}`}/>
  </button>
}
export default MyButton;
```

or

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from 'react';
import downArrow from "./downArrow.png"
function MyButton(){
  const [open ,setOpen]= useState(false);
  return <button onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>Buuton<img src={downArrow}
         className={`${open ? 'rotate-180 transition-all' : ' transition-all'}`}/>
  </button>
}
export default MyButton;
```